# Modify a .csv file in powershell automatically

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I try to create a powershell script, to perform a few steps:

- In a specific folder, I put a .xlsx file, it converts it to csv. Until now I got this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

Function Convert-CsvInBatch
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$Folder
    )
    $ExcelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.xlsx -Recurse

    $excelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excelApp.DisplayAlerts = $false

    $ExcelFiles | ForEach-Object {
        $workbook = $excelApp.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)
        $csvFilePath = $_.FullName -replace "\.xlsx$", ".csv"
        $workbook.SaveAs($csvFilePath, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlCSV)
        $workbook.Close()
    }

    # Release Excel Com Object resource
    $excelApp.Workbooks.Close()
    $excelApp.Visible = $true
    Start-Sleep 5
    $excelApp.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelApp) | Out-Null
}

#
# 0. Prepare the folder path which contains all excel files
$FolderPath = "C:\exacthpath"

Convert-CsvInBatch -Folder $FolderPath
```

- The columns in the file, are still there, so I want to remove them, and insert a ';' instead, like:
  H;1;43;185;

At this point I'm stuck. I can import it into Powershell like:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\folder\filename.csv' | ForEach-Object {
$_
}
```

I get this look, and the most important task is here, in the first row only:

H;1;43;185;

This should be modified into:

H;01;43;185

the rest should be left untouched.
After I need to export back it into a CSV file, like:

```
Export-Csv -Path 'C:\folder\modified_filename.csv'
```

But this whole process should be inserted in one single powershell script, which performs the above steps on it's own. So in short:

- identifies any .xlsx file - regardless of it's name
- convers it into .csv
- modifies the outlook of the document, to separate the columns with a ";"
- modify the first line to have 'H;01;43;185' - this is a static line, it will always look like this
- save the created file as a final .csv file

Can you help me somehow to include/optimize the above scripts and let powershell perform the modification too? Example content of a file like this (final look) Usually it includes more 1000+ lines:

```
H;01;43;185
D;111;3;1042;2
D;222;3;1055;3
D;333;3;1085;1
T;3;;;
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Armin

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is that I think you'd be interested in the excellent module [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0). The Excel com interface is slow

Comment: What is the delimiter character actually used when your Excel creates the CSV? Is that a comma or a semi-colon (`;`). If it is a semi-colon, your `Import-Csv -Path 'C:\folder\filename.csv'` won't work because without `-Delimiter ';'` it will import all rows as one single column.  What is the logic to have the header like `'H;01;43;185` when apparently the data in the file seems to have 5 columns, not just these four.

Comment: @Theo The delimiter character for me is a semi-colon, the same as in the examples. And yes, orignally it is a 5 column document, but in the first row the 5th column's semi-colon needs to be deleted, or the program which supposed to import this file won't recognize it.

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld, I try this way, but as the computer is an office one - so I need admin rights to perform this. We'll sell...

Comment: Check your`$env:PSModulePath`. Probably it contains a path within your personal home/profile folder. You can place modules there as a user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as you say in your comment, your Excel already creates a csv with the semi-colon as delimiter, you can do this inside the loop, just below `$workbook.Close()`

```
# read the file created by Excel as string array
$data = Get-Content $csvFilePath
# overwrite the file with just the new header
Set-Content -Path $csvFilePath -Value 'H;01;43;185'
# add the rest of the data to the file
$data[1..($data.Count -1)] | Add-Content -Path $csvFilePath
```

P.S. I would delete the lines

```
$excelApp.Visible = $true
Start-Sleep 5
```

because I don't see the need to have Excel show itself and pause the function for 5 seconds.. Instead, have Excel not show at all so it will work a lot faster by adding

```
$excelApp.Visible = $false
```

right after you have created the $excelApp

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! :)